# Run-time error 440 Property is Read Only - On one Macro

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

as the title says I am having this error poping up everytime I try to run a script.

I am frustrated. This was not happening a few days ago and to add salt to the stab other scripts (not written by me) are running perfectly fine. I have absolutely no idea on how to fix this. Has anyone had a similar issue, ever?

Literally from night to day the Macro I was writting stopped working in the first few lines.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim maxi As String

  Set GuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
  Set App = GuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
  Set Con = App.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
  Set session = Con.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
    Set sessioninfo = session.Info
```

That is my script and I get the error by the line:

`Set session = Con.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection`

Here is a screenshot:

[image: My macro and the line with the error]

And here is a screenshot of the same code in another macro and which is actually running:

[image: I cannot believe this]

I looked into the Public Sessions in the beginning of the script, but they do not work for me, plus as I said, this was working up to a few days ago. Can anyone point out a suggestion on how can I check what is the difference between these two macros, or what might have happened to mine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing you variable name?
Maybe something like 'ses'.
Just to be sure this is not overwritting another existent variable.

Also, I would try to unset the variable before using it.
This is what I usually do when starting my code:

```vb
  Set Session = Nothing
  Set Con = Nothing
  Set App = Nothing
  Set GuiAuto = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you Carlos. I actually found out what happened and will post the answer.
I did add your unsets to my code.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, Outlook Object Library was checked in the References as well as the Microsoft Office Package. I believe that, somehow, both references nullified one another.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue - try to rename variable 'Session' to for example 'SAPSession' - for me it has worked.